# Distance / Proximity from cck location field ? not from user or node location?

Tags: entities, location

I try to get a distance between cck location nodes / users but I didn't succeed at that point because the only avalaible views field to do that is  "EMPLACEMENT : DISTANCE / PROXIMITY" which concerns node location or user location, not cck location field.

How to get that point ?

Regards,
Yoann

Answer (score 3):

Results may vary based upon your drupal version, but basically when you create a proximity filter:

[image]

the first option is "Node location" but when you click on that:

[image]

it will allow you to use a Location CCK field as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Ok  for Location CCK field linked to nodes but it seems there is a problem with Location CCK field linked to users bacause the "Location to use" is not available for "User's Latitude / Longitude from views uid argument". Actually I added a location cck field to users and this field is only available through "node's Latitude / Longitude frow views nid argument".

Comment: You must be on drupal 7 then, and I don't have an answer to that, for in drupal 6 land, you can't add cck fields to users :)  Here we'd add a location field to a content profile node type and then could use that.

Comment: Ok I found a way to use locationn cck field without node or user location. I did as you told me but I needed to add a PHP code to get the initial position of the current user. Now it works fine and I get the correct distances. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Glad I was able to help out a bit!  You may want to post your code for others to follow.

Comment: ok it's done. Hope it's useful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I used in the "php code for latitue, longitude" origin section in the "Emplacement: Distance / Proximity field" views :

global $user;
global $databases;
$res = db_set_active('default');
$query1 = db_query("SELECT field_lien_adresse_utilisateur_target_id FROM
 {field_data_field_lien_adresse_utilisateur} WHERE entity_id = :uid", array('uid' => $user->uid));
$results1 = $query1->fetchAll();
$query2 = db_query("SELECT field_adresse_utilisateur_lid FROM
 {field_data_field_adresse_utilisateur} WHERE entity_id = :entity_id", array('entity_id' => $results1[0]->field_lien_adresse_utilisateur_target_id));
$results2 = $query2->fetchAll();
$query3 = db_query("SELECT latitude, longitude FROM {location} WHERE lid = :lid",
 array('lid' => $results2[0]->field_adresse_utilisateur_lid));
$results3 = $query3->fetchAll();
$result['latitude'] = (float) $results3[0]->latitude;
$result['longitude'] = (float) $results3[0]->longitude;
return $result;

Then I got the latitude and longitude of the current user.

Hope it's useful.